# Return String[] from Go using cgo

Tags: java, go, jna, cgo

I have to call a Go function from Java. 
I am using `cgo` and `JNA` for doing this.

The only thing that the Go routine does is allocating memory and return a `char**`. From Java side, I am receiving the `char**` using `String[]` as is mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/PointersAndArrays.md).

Below are the details of the C helper and Go functions:

```
static char** cmalloc(int size) {
    return (char**) malloc(size * sizeof(char*));
}

static void setElement(char **a, char *s, int index) {
    a[index] = s;
}

//export getSearchKeysA
func getSearchKeysA() **C.char {
    set_char := C.cmalloc(1)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(set_char))
    C.setElement(set_char, C.CString("hello world"), C.int(0))
    return set_char
}
```

The Java side:

```
String[] getSearchKeysA();
```

The error I am getting is:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff6b15323e, pid=92979, tid=0x0000000000000c07
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_192-b12) (build 1.8.0_192-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.192-b12 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsystem_kernel.dylib+0x723e]  __pthread_kill+0xa
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/dfb3/datafabric/pocs/go-java-connector/hs_err_pid92979.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

**What I have noticed is that the issue appears when malloc is allocating memory.**

I already tried doing `ulimit -c unlimited` and removing the `defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(set_char))` from the method.

What can be the cause of the error and how can I solve it? Is there any other way of returning a `[]string` from Go using `JNA`?

Update because of typo and base on @PeterSO answer  :

1. I wrote initially malloc(0) but it should be malloc(1)
2. `func C.CString(string) *C.char`, it should allocate the memory for me, is
   not?

Comment: You passed 0 as the size, so your malloc call uses `0 * sizeof(char *)`, which is of course zero. You have therefore done the equivalent of `return malloc(0)`. Calling C's `malloc` with zero can either return NULL, in which case you must not use the pointer, or can return a pointer to a memory area with zero usable bytes. You then use `1 * sizeof(char *)` of these zero usable bytes to store things.

Comment: Meanwhile, as [peterSO noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59496419/1256452), now that you have written (e.g.) 4 or 8 bytes to the zero bytes you allocated, you then free the zero bytes you allocated (or call `free(NULL)` which is a no-op—but if `malloc` returned `NULL`, we've probably already crashed), and then return the now-invalidated C memory pointer.

Comment: @torek I am sorry, it was a typo when I was writing the question here. I updated and question based on PeterSO answer and your comments here.

Comment: Update: the Java documentation says that Java's `String []` works like C's `argv` so when you build the C argument vector you'll need a series of `char *` values that ends with `NULL`. There's probably a better way to deal with this, but given what you have so far you'd need to allocate `2 * sizeof(char *)`, set the one at `[0]` to a C string, and set the one at `[1]` to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally return a `String[]` from `GO` using `cgo`.

I will leave the functions signatures:

```
//export getSearchKeys
func getSearchKeys(numKeysByReference *C.int) **C.char {
  *numKeysByReference = // ... some value
  // Using the C helper defined above
  set_char := C.cmalloc(*numKeysByReference)
  // Logic allocating and populating C.char[i .. *numKeysByReference]
  // ...
  return set_char
}
```

After creating the `**C.char` structure using `cgo`, on `Java` side, I am receiving the data as follow:

```
IntByReference intByReference = new IntByReference();
PointerByReference array = lib.getSearchKeys(intByReference);
String[] results = array.getPointer().getStringArray(0, intByReference.getValue());
```

As @PeterSO mentioned, we have call `defer C.free()` after using it. Otherwise, it will be deallocated after returning.